# SharePoint CSOM Unit Testing

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, unit-testing

I am currently using CSOM to upload/download files from SharePoint 2013 sites. I would like to know what would be the best way to unit test my operations. Is there a way I could create a fake SharePoint site within my test and then running my tests against this fake site.

For starters I would like to know how I could unit test this `var clientContext = new clientContext(url)`.

I would first like to create a fake SharePoint site with this url and then test this above piece of code to check if the context was loaded or if there were any errors. The urls will be dynamic based on some conditions and I would like to test if for a particular condition the particular context generation was successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a "fake" SharePoint site using the SharePoint Emulators. This process is covered in detail in this talk from TechEd 2013

[Testing and Debugging Microsoft SharePoint Applications with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B332)

> Visual Studio 2012 updates 1 and 2 have introduced a host of new
>   capabilities to make it easier to test and debug SharePoint 2010 and
>   SharePoint 2013 applications. In this demo-packed session, see how you
>   can write unit tests for SharePoint which can run with the aid of
>   SharePoint Emulators, without requiring a physical SharePoint
>   deployment. Learn how to author coded UI tests which allow you to
>   script tests which simulate users interacting with your SharePoint
>   applications. Learn how you can compose web performance tests into
>   load tests which can be used to test the performance and scalability
>   of your SharePoint applications. Finally, see how IntelliTrace can be
>   used to go deep into the SharePoint stack and understand exactly
>   what’s happening when things go wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately emulators is for the server object model only.